# DB options connection string doesnt choose the one i specified

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, abp

I have an ASP.NET core api with the abp framework, when i put a connectionstring into my appsettings.json for my backend to connect to, it never picks the connectionstring i specified.

the string will look something like

"Default": "Server=projectname-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=projectnamedb" + the login

but when i debug and check for the connectionstring it always takes a localhost variant with ProjectnameDb as the database name.

connectionstring = "Server=localhost; Database=projectNameDb; Trusted_Connection=True;"

apb had some info about a connectionstring being generated if not found, but even when i put an appsettings.json in every module with the desired string it still doesn't get picked up.

this makes it impossible for me to start up the app because even when i changed the connectionsting to the one they use it also doesn't pick this up, my migrations don't get applied and therefor entityframework throws an error that some fields are not found.

Comment: Is this 'abp' specific? Or do you think this is a basic issue about asp.net core? Anyhow, you should probably show us how are getting the connection string out of the configuration, and how is it injected into the DbContext, i.e. the contents of `Startup.ConfigureServices`, and the constructor of the DbContext (and/or the `OnConfiguring` method, if you're using that).

Comment: Add your `appsettings.json` file content

Answer (score 0):

For database creating, you can check MyProject.**DbMigrator** appsettings.json.

> apb had some info about a connectionstring being generated if not
> found, but even when i put an appsettings.json in every module with
> the desired string it still doesn't get picked up.

Putting appsettings to every module wouldn't work since appsettings is the configuration for the **running application**.

If you are running your application on containers, you may also want to check if your configuration is overridden by environment variable.